# Where do you think my data change from dataframe into list? Because this error appear AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, list, dataframe

> I'm trying to code for undersampling negative class data (majority class in imbalanced dataset) by only keeping the support vectors. Thus in the process I need to rebuild the dataset by removing some of the not needed data granular support vector machine repetitive undersampling. I'm trying to rebuild the dataset in the def rebuild function.

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

class gsvm(object):
    def __init__(self, C = 100,
                 T = 10,class_weight = 'balanced',
                 degree = 3,gamma='auto', kernel='rbf'
                 ):
        self.C = C
        self.T = T
        self.class_weight = class_weight
        self.degree = degree
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.kernel = kernel
        self.allSVC = SVC(C = self.C, class_weight=self.class_weight,
                      degree=self.degree, gamma = self.gamma,
                      kernel= self.kernel)

    def rebuild(self, xTrain, yTrain, sv, xNLSV):  # rebuild SVC
        xNew = []
        yNew = []
        count = 0
        for i in range(0, len(yTrain)):
            if yTrain.iloc[i] == 1:
                xNew.append(xTrain.iloc[i])
                yNew.append(yTrain.iloc[i])
            else:
                if i not in sv:
                    xNew.append(xTrain.iloc[i])
                    yNew.append(yTrain.iloc[i])
                    count += 1
                else:
                    xNLSV.append(xTrain.iloc[i])
        return xNew, yNew, xNLSV, count

    def fit(self, x, y):
        #
        xPos = []
        xNeg = []
        xTrain = []
        yTrain = []
        xlastTrain = []
        ylastTrain = []

        for i in range(0, len(y)):
            if y.iloc[i] == 1:
                xPos.append(x.iloc[i])
                xlastTrain.append(x.iloc[i])
                ylastTrain.append(y.iloc[i])
                xTrain.append(x.iloc[i])
                yTrain.append(y.iloc[i])
            else:
                xNeg.append(x.iloc[i])
                xTrain.append(x.iloc[i])
                yTrain.append(y.iloc[i])
        xNLSV = []
        iterRecord = 0
        for i in range(0, self.T):
            svc = SVC(C = self.C, class_weight=self.class_weight,
                      degree=self.degree, gamma = self.gamma,
                      kernel= self.kernel)
            print (iterRecord)
            iterRecord += 1
            svc.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
            sv = svc.support_  # This is support vector
            xTrain, yTrain, xNLSV, lastMar = self.rebuild(xTrain, yTrain, sv, xNLSV)  # rebuild sample
            print (lastMar)
            if lastMar < 0.1 * len(xPos):
                break

        for i in xNLSV:
            xlastTrain.append(i)
            ylastTrain.append(0)

        self.allSVC.fit(xlastTrain, ylastTrain)

    def predict(self, x):
        return  self.allSVC.predict(x)
```

> The problem is, all of the data I used are formated as dataframe but when I tried to rebuild the sample, after fitting the class into svm, this line:

```
xTrain, yTrain, xNLSV, lastMar = self.rebuild(xTrain, yTrain, sv, xNLSV)  # rebuild sample
```

> I got the error below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 gsvm().fit(X_train1,y_train1)

Input In [14], in gsvm.fit(self, x, y)
     66 svc.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
     67 sv = svc.support_  # This is support vector
---> 68 xTrain, yTrain, xNLSV, lastMar = self.rebuild(xTrain, yTrain, sv, xNLSV)  # rebuild sample
     69 print (lastMar)
     70 if lastMar < 0.1 * len(xPos):

Input In [14], in gsvm.rebuild(self, xTrain, yTrain, sv, xNLSV)
     24 count = 0
     25 for i in range(0, len(yTrain)):
---> 26     if yTrain.iloc[i] == 1:
     27         xNew.append(xTrain.iloc[i])
     28         yNew.append(yTrain.iloc[i])

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

> Where do you think my dataset change from dataframe into list?

Comment: AttributeError raises on line 26, and there is no reference to the yTrain before line 26. My bet would be yTrain was already a list before the gsvm class.

Comment: In the `rebuild` function, `yNew = []`
then the function has `return xNew, yNew, xNLSV, count`, 
then the return value is used in `xTrain, yTrain, xNLSV, lastMar = ...`